# Shower Curb Penetrations

Tags: shower, waterproofing, glass

The person who installed my frameless shower glass mounted two brackets directly into the shower curb. There is some silicone visible around the brackets... I'm not sure if silicone was used in the screw holes.

The curb is made of quartz composite and the waterproofing underneath is hot mop.

The glass was over a year ago, and I haven't seen signs of moisture damage yet, but it does concern me. Is this a big problem?

Thanks.

Edit: Here is [a photo of one of the brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eat7l.jpg)

Comment: Hi Peter. A photo or two would go a long way here to clarify your question,

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. I added a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything out of place there.   The shower curb is there to keep water from exiting the shower.   The silicone is used so that water doesn't go under the bracket.   There isn't much the silicone is doing as waterproofing, although it is keeping the bracket from being damaged and maybe a tiny bit of water in.    There is nothing that concerns me in that photo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had read that shower curb penetrations lead to moisture damage, even when silicone is applied. But if it's not a cause for concern, that's great.

Comment: @Peter - Maybe in a rare case on tile where you penetrate the waterproofing.   However with a thick slab of quartz there is almost no change the mounting went through it and even if it did there is really very little room for water to get in.  This looks like a good install.